# JPA-hib not saving to database, but reading db (mysql, Hikari, tomcat 9, spring boot 2.1.8)

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the latest versions of mysql, Hikari, spring boot 2 in a multi tenant app, using datasource set programmatically.

I am able to read table entries in the (mysql) databases, but not able to update or insert or modify.

Basically the following, 'believe is leading to queuing the save requests

===========

```
j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2019-09-25 10:05:20.758 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
```

=========

resulting in queueing the insert

========
EntityIdentityInsertAction for [com.xx.xx.xx.user] object

```
2019-09-25 10:05:20.761 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[com.xx.xx.user#<delayed:2>]]
```

========

How to set the underlying JDBC connection to auto commit?

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Have tried:

1. repo.saveAndFlush() and repo.flush() -- both give me exception that there is no transaction in progress
2. have serialized the object/table-entity
3. have set ds.setAutoCommit(true);
       ds.setReadOnly(false);   // ds is the datasource
4. In application.properties have set 
   spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true

=====Hikari pool config dump shows auto commit is true ===

```
2019-09-25 10:05:20.795 DEBUG 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2019-09-25 10:05:20.795 DEBUG 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
```

========end of Hikari config dump ====

But, the JDBC trace shows auotcommit to false while calling repo.save(user)

```
019-09-25 10:05:20.758 DEBUG 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2019-09-25 10:05:20.758 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2019-09-25 10:05:20.758 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2019-09-25 10:05:20.759 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterBeginCallback

2019-09-25 10:05:20.759 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .i.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=1, owner=null
2019-09-25 10:05:20.759 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Opened Session [c0c25dff-2c0a-4996-b352-1ac4d49e48e8] at timestamp: 1569423920759
2019-09-25 10:05:20.760 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value: 0
2019-09-25 10:05:20.760 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Transient instance of: com.xx.xx.xx.user
2019-09-25 10:05:20.760 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2019-09-25 10:05:20.760 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [com.xx.xx.xx.user#<null>]
2019-09-25 10:05:20.760 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [com.xx.xx.xx.user] object
2019-09-25 10:05:20.761 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[com.xx.xx.user#<delayed:2>]]
2019-09-25 10:05:20.761 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding resolved non-early insert action
2019-09-25 10:05:20.761 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session [c0c25dff-2c0a-4996-b352-1ac4d49e48e8]
2019-09-25 10:05:20.761 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@3cba167b]
2019-09-25 10:05:20.761 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Closing logical connection
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Logical connection closed
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 DEBUG 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#beforeCompletionCallback
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : SessionImpl#beforeTransactionCompletion()
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Automatically flushing session
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .t.i.SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl : SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl.notifySynchronizationsBeforeTransactionCompletion
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Preparing to commit transaction via JDBC Connection.commit()
2019-09-25 10:05:20.762 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Transaction committed via JDBC Connection.commit()
2019-09-25 10:05:20.763 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : re-enabling auto-commit on JDBC Connection after completion of JDBC-based transaction
2019-09-25 10:05:20.763 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : LogicalConnection#afterTransaction
2019-09-25 10:05:20.763 TRACE 2643 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
```

=========================
Repo is

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository {}

========
Entity is

```
@Persistent
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

   // private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;    
    @Column(name = "username")
     private String username;

   ===Rest of fields with setters and getters==


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + this.id + ", username=" + this.username +", email="+ this.email+ " 
            + "]";
}

}
```

service class is

```
@Service
@Persistent
@Transactional(transactionManager="tenantTransactionManager")     
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    public List<User> listAll() {

    return repo.findAll();
    }




public void save(User user) { 

                try {

                    repo.save(user);

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public User get(long id) { return repo.findById(id).get();}



public void delete(long id) { repo.deleteById(id); } 

    }
```

=======tenantManager===

@Bean(name = "tenantEntityManagerFactory")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
       ) {
    //cleaned up on code not directly related

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 


    emfBean.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[] { User.class.getPackage().getName(),
                    UserRepository.class.getPackage().getName(),
                    UserService.class.getPackage().getName() });
    emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT,
            MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);

    properties.put(
            org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER,  connectionProvider);

    properties.put(
            org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER,
            tenantResolver);



    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT,
            "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");      

    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
    properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);

    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.autocommit", "true");
    properties.put("spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true"); 

    emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);   

    return emfBean;
}
```

}
=====and datasource provider===

public static DataSource createAndConfigureDataSource( {

```
    //=======================
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setUsername(xxx);
    ds.setPassword(xxx);
    ds.setJdbcUrl(xxxx);
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");   

    ds.setConnectionTimeout(20000);

    // Minimum number of idle connections in the pool
    ds.setMinimumIdle(10);
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
    ds.setIdleTimeout(300000);
    ds.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
    ds.setAutoCommit(true);
    ds.setReadOnly(false);

    return ds;
```

## } }

application.properties ====

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.com=TRACE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=TRACE
    logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
logging.level.org.hibernate=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.autoCommit=true
```

=====

```
@Bean(name = "tenantTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory tenantEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(tenantEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Comment: One does not use autoCommit=true together with Hibernate/JPA. With Spring normally the `@Transactional` annotation is used to activate (Hibernate) transaction and that's it. However, the repositories already have the `@Transactional` functionality. Could you remove the autoCommit setting and turn on showSql=true? And tell us whether Hibernate issues any SQL?

Comment: Probably the repository would be of interest. Could you please show us the repository and its usage?

Comment: repo is :  _at_ Repository _at_Transactional(transactionManager="tenantTransactionManager")  
public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<user, Long> {   //tried with and without Transactional annotation for repo }                                                         and Entity  is: _at_Persistent
_at_Entity
_at_Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {


    _at_Id
    _at_GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    _at_Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

  other fields with getters and setters
} _at_  is annotation symbol

Comment: Don't add additional information/code/xml as comments. Instead edit your question. Those comments are unreadable. Show how hibernate is configured.

Comment: You have extra transactioManager specified on the repository. That's not far away from the source of your problem. And yes, please do not add code in comments,  enhance the question instead.

Comment: When every other aspect was left to spring/spring boot defaults, then removing the `transactionManager="tenantTransactionManager"` would very much likely solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for enhancing the question with your service and repository. Now, where is the transaction manager called "tenantTransactionManager" supposed to come from? Could you show us that configuration?

Comment: Thanks all, I believe all the info is now in my q. The db is read perfectly with repo.findAll etc. But writing back to db is what getting queued at jdbc layer. Somewhere auto commit is set false at jdbc layer. The Hikaricp resets to auto commit when the transaction finishes. I commented out all @Transcational but the result is the same -- no write into db. Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Stop fiddling with auto commit)) I still do not see any bean definition called `tenantTransactionManager.` No wonder you do not have a Hibernate trasaction and cannot write.

Comment: will stop fiddling after get this right :) Sure. Will follow that. added code on tenantTransactionmanager Thanks @Michal

Answer (score 1):

Finally, thanks to all. Struggled for a week on this. Minor Qualifier on the
@Bean(name = "tenantTransactionManager") with @Qualifier("tenantEntityManagerFactory") on emf did the trick.

Yes, stopped fiddling with autoCommit and removed all additional transactional as suggested. Much appreciated for your pointers. Thank you.